# How to internationalize a PHP Web Application?

Tags: php, internationalization, multilingual, multibyte

We have a PHP application that was designed to work for a particular country, with normal characters. This application has normal modules that are usually found in the most of the applications, such as register/login module, text editor, post texts, read/write to the database, search module...

I already did it in the past, but I can't remember all the steps to transform this application into an international one, supporting all kind of characters (chinese, japanese, russian, etc).

I have already developed some scripts in order to:

- Change the codification of the files to utf-8
- Change the codification of the database (database itself, tables and text/varchar fields)
- Set the database to utf-8 everytime I make an instance of it (`SET NAMES utf8`)
- Change all string functions to [multibyte](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php) (e.g.: `substr()` to `mb_substr()`)
- Get into the templates and setting the encoding to utf-8 (`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`)

**Edit**

- Unit testing (thanks to Marcel Djaman)
- Add `accept-charset="UTF-8"` to the forms (thanks to Jason Spicer)
- Use `iconv` (thanks to Robert Pounder)

Is there any other step I should take?

How can I check in an application with thousands of pages that it work?

Comment: As a little tip, unit testing is a god send for testing stuff like this.

Comment: Thanks! I will add it to the list! I was thinking also of taking screenshots with some technology as Selenium

Comment: unit testing?!? nothing related to internationalize

Comment: Well I don't think it has nothing to do. I am changing dozens of string functions to multibyte, so the results could be really different!

Comment: I'd also make sure to add accept-charset="UTF-8" to your forms. Just a nudge to browsers to make sure they send content in UTF-8.

Comment: true! thanks, i will add it to the list

Comment: This question is too broad to give a meaningful answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing you have really missed out is `utf8_encoding` / `utf8_decoding` over pages.

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php

Also may need to use `iconv`:

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php

**NOTE:**

`utf8_encode()` will only convert ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8 so you will have to use `iconv` in this instance.